# Change paper size and orientation in an rmarkdown pdf

Tags: r, latex, knitr, r-markdown

I'd like to create a PDF using rmarkdown that is A3 (or 11x17, ideally) and in landscape orientation. I can get it to do one or the other by specifying options in the YAML header, but not both at the same time. Here's my best attempt - the classoption values each work individually, but not together:

```
---
title: "Test"
output: 
  pdf_document:
    toc: true
    number_sections: true
documentclass: article
classoption: 
  landscape
  a3paper
---
```

[This question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25866788/how-can-i-change-paper-size-when-using-knit-pdf-in-rstudio) is related, but doesn't have the answer in this case. Thanks in advance for any help you can provide!

Answer (score 16, accepted):

It doesn't seem to be documented, but you can include more than one `classoption` by separating the options with commas or by using a bulleted list with hyphens. Either of the following will work:

```
---
title: "Test"
output: 
  pdf_document:
    toc: true
    number_sections: true
documentclass: article
classoption: 
  - landscape
  - a3paper
---


---
title: "Test"
output: 
  pdf_document:
    toc: true
    number_sections: true
documentclass: article
classoption: landscape, a3paper
---
```