# How to specify a customized paper size in r markdown

Tags: r, latex, r-markdown, knitr

I am using R Markdown to produce a booklet with specific height and length measures. Is there a way to specify to R Markdown to produce the article in 5.5"x8.5" measures.

I saw questions asked about producing A4 size pdf [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47171585/change-paper-size-and-orientation-in-an-rmarkdown-pdf) but that does not help as my measure is very specific.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Use the geometry option in the YAML (which becomes options to the geometry package in LaTeX).  For example:

````
---
title: "Title"
author: "Me"
geometry: paperheight=8.5in,paperwidth=5.5in,margin=1in
output:
    pdf_document
---

```{r setup, include=FALSE}
knitr::opts_chunk$set(echo = TRUE)
```

## R Markdown

This is an R Markdown document. Markdown is a simple formatting
syntax for authoring HTML, PDF, and MS Word documents. For more
details on using R Markdown see <http://rmarkdown.rstudio.com>.
````