# possible to access '\textwidth' during knitr run for proportional image scaling

Tags: r, graphics, r-markdown, knitr, bookdown

When compiling to PDF, `out.width` for code chunks producing plotted output in `knitr` appears to default to `\textwidth` (or rather `\maxwidth`; see [here](https://yihui.name/knitr/options/#code-chunk)).

I would like to be able to - during the `knitr` run - determine what `\textwidth` actually equates to, such that I can use the value to proportionally size the height of my graphical output using `out.height`. I'm using (my own) package `multipanelfigure` to assemble compound figures as they are customary in the sciences and need the real dimensions to do that.

Can that be achieved?

Comment: Have a look at `knit_hooks$set()`. You can replace things using somthing like this: `knit_hooks$set(document = function(x) gsub("\\textwidth", "\\textwidth", x, fixed = TRUE))` (Note: I think document is not the right type to replace here but wanted to give you something to start from).

Comment: That can be achieved. Though I am not quite sure what it is ;) You are talking about the width of chunks (output?), but `out.width` is an option relevant for plotting. Also, what do you mean by panels?

Comment: I edited the question to clarify - better interpretable now?

Answer (score 0):

I don't think you can query the value, but you can set it.  If you are producing single column output, it will be the page width minus each margin width.  Those can be set using the methods described here:  https://stackoverflow.com/a/54526289/2554330.  Standard letter size paper is 8.5in wide, 11in high with 1in margins on both sides; standard A4 paper is 210mm wide, 297mm high.  I forget what the standard A4 margins are.

So if you are not changing margins and are using standard letter size paper, you can assume the width is 6.5in.