# How to change the paper size in a rmarkdown word_document?

Tags: r, r-markdown, knitr

I have some wide result tables I need to share in a (sad) word document. I noticed they fit well in A3 format. Many answers ([How can I change paper size when using Knit PDF in RStudio?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25866788/how-can-i-change-paper-size-when-using-knit-pdf-in-rstudio), [Change paper size and orientation in an rmarkdown pdf](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47171585/change-paper-size-and-orientation-in-an-rmarkdown-pdf?rq=1), [How to specify a customized paper size in r markdown](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54526126/how-to-specify-a-customized-paper-size-in-r-markdown), [Change paper size and orientation in an rmarkdown pdf](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47171585/change-paper-size-and-orientation-in-an-rmarkdown-pdf)) explain how to change the paper size for `output:pdf_document`. Is is possible to change the paper size for `output:word_document`, more specifically `output: bookdown::word_document2`?

Reproducible example where I place `papersize: a3` in the rmarkdown yaml front header:

```
---
title: "test A3 paper"
papersize: a3
output:
    word_document
---

# Title

generate this document with:

    rmarkdown::render("a3.Rmd")
```

The output word document is still in the default US letter format, not in A3.

Comment: Have you tried creating a reference doc in A3? https://rmarkdown.rstudio.com/articles_docx.html

Answer (score 2):

I would prefer another answer if it's possible to avoid creating a reference document.

Edit the word document that was generated by `rmarkdown::render` and change the format to A3. Save it under a new name, for example "a3_template.docx".
Then modify the yaml front matter to call a reference document:

```
---
title: "test A3 paper"
output:
  word_document:
    reference_docx: a3_template.docx
---
```